# Save string to xml file (UWP) c#

Tags: c#, uwp

I am trying to save an string to an xml file and am recieving the following error:

**An exception of type 'System.UnauthorizedAccessException' occurred in System.IO.FileSystem.dll but was not handled in user code
Additional information: Access to the path 'c:\users\brandon\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\UniversalTestApp\UniversalTestApp\bin\x86\Debug\AppX\xmlfile.xml' is denied.**

Reading further into the issue it would seem that I don't have the approriate permissions to complete this save.  How would I go about

```
    private async void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var bookmark = new Bookmark();
        bookmark.Button = cmbButton.SelectedIndex;
        bookmark.Name = txtName.Text;
        bookmark.URL = txtURL.Text;
        string output = SerializeToXml(bookmark);
        XmlDocument xdox = new XmlDocument();
        File.WriteAllText("xmlfile.xml",output);        
    }
```

Comment: setting those permissions?  (to finish my question)

Comment: If you try to read or write the file before, this is may be why. Use the keyword `using` https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx

Answer (score 1):

As it turns out the reason for the error message is that you can only access certain file system locations by default in UWP.  I made some modifications to my code and it is now working correctly.  Thanks to those who tried to help.

```
    private async void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var bookmark = new Bookmark();

        StorageFolder storageFolder = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
        StorageFile createFile = await storageFolder.CreateFileAsync("bookmark.xml", CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);

        bookmark.Button = cmbButton.SelectedIndex;
        bookmark.Name = txtName.Text;
        bookmark.URL = txtURL.Text;
        var output = SerializeToXml(bookmark);

        StorageFile sampleFile = await storageFolder.GetFileAsync("bookmark.xml");
        await FileIO.WriteTextAsync(sampleFile, output);   
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Try to run your application "as administrator"

Comment: Admittedly before I tried that I thought you were right.  Didn't work though. Thanks for the suggestion.